# Perform a task only at start of an Android application

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

In my app I want a string to be passed to the server only at the startup of application.

I have used SharedPreferences to check if the string is sent or not.

this code runs at star of MainActivity

```
        pref=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        Sent=pref.getString("ID_SENT", "");
        if(Sent.equals(""))
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
            editor.putString("ID_SENT","NO");
            editor.commit();
            Sent=pref.getString("ID_SENT","");
        }
```

Now after the string is sent to the server in onPostExecute of AsyncTask this code is used to set the variable ID_SENT to YES:

```
                    Sent=pref.getString("ID_SENT", "");
                    if(Sent.equals("NO"))
                    {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
                        editor.putString("ID_SENT","YES");
                        editor.commit();
                    }
```

Now the problem is when I close the app and start the app again it doesn't send the string to server because it finds ID_SENT set to YES.

So is there any way so that I can set ID_SENT to no as the back button is pressed while on MainActivity?

**EDIT:**

I set launch mode of MainActivity to singleTop. So now activity resumes whenever I press home button from another activities. And the string is not sent everytime because MainActivity is only resumed.

Comment: What do you mean by start? Do you want to sent whenever onCreateonCreate is called?

Answer (score 1):

> So is there any way so that I can set ID_SENT to no as the back button is pressed while on MainActivity?

Yes,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // do your save logic here
}
```

Or you could `override onDestroy()`, this may be safer in case Android destroys the `Activity` to reclaim memory

Comment: I tried that. but when i go to another activity from MainActivity , onDestroy is called and the ID_SENT is changed to NO. Now I have put home button(MainActivity) link on every page so whenever that button is pressed MainActivity is called again and it again sends the string to server.

Comment: Do you call `finish()` on your `MainActivity`?

Comment: Well the `onBackPressed()` override will work for what you want, I believe. Give it a try and let me know. But that seems odd to me that `onDestroy()` is called everytime

Comment: Is that because i haven't put onPause method?

Comment: It shouldn't be, `onPause()` will be called by Android and do its normal stuff in there if you don't `override`. `onDestroy()` shouldn't be called unless you call `finish()` or Android needs to save space

Comment: public void goToHomePage()
    {
     Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
     i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     startActivity(i);
    }   This the method which I call from another activity for home link. and when this method is called the onDestroy is called for the mainactivity